# Programmatically create Venn diagrams at scale?

Tags: r

I would like to create a Venn Diagram like the following:
[image]

The challenge is to have the circles and intersections with the right proportions. That is:

- Group 1 should be 15% of the universe, group 2 83%, and group 3 30%.
- The intersection between G1 G2 and G3 should be 7% of the universe
- etc

Is there a way of doing this? This is what I have right now:

```
    library(VennDiagram)

    grid.newpage()


    draw.triple.venn(area1 = 15, area2 = 83, area3 = 30, n12 = 13, n23 = 28, n13 = 7, 
                     n123 = 7, category = c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"), lty = "blank", 
                     fill = c("skyblue", "pink1", "mediumorchid"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works a bit better, not sure if the overlap is completely correct though

```
library(venneuler)
venn <- venneuler(c(A=83, B=30, C=15, "A&B"=28, "B&C"=7, "A&C"=13, "A&B&C"=7))
plot(venn)
```

Comment: unfortunately, precision in venn is impossible.  approximate is the best that can be achieved.

Comment: @timelyportfolio let me know if you create some fancy htmlwidget for this

Comment: I did make http://www.buildingwidgets.com/blog/2015/6/5/week-22-d3vennr, but I have not had a chance to update to the newest d3-venn with lots of new features.